# How to use "google-charts-node" npm package with dynamic parameters

Tags: node-modules

I am trying to create charts using "google-charts-node" npm via REST api but getting this error everytime when I try to pass dynamic data from request body in the drawChart function but it works fine when I passed static parameters

Here is my code

```
const GoogleChartsNode = require('google-charts-node');
const express=require('express')
const body_parser=require('body-parser')

const fs = require('fs');
const app=express()

app.use(body_parser.json());

async function drawChart(body) {

var arr=[]
arr=body.chartData
console.log(arr)

    var data =  google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arr);
  
    var options = {
      title: 'Revenue of C2C 2020',
      chartArea: { width: '50%' },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Revenue',
        minValue: 0,
      },
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Products',
      },
    };
      var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(container);
  
   chart.draw(data, options);
  }

  const Img= async(body) => {
    const image = await  GoogleChartsNode.render(drawChart(body), {
      width: 400,
      height: 300,
    });
    return image
}
var bodyData

const getDataFirst=(data,callback)=>{
    console.log('func',data)
    callback(data)
}

app.post('/drawcharts', async (req,res)=>{
bodyData=req.body
getDataFirst(bodyData,async(data)=>{
    console.log('callback',data)
    const v= await Img(data)
    console.log(v)
})
```

And getting this error

```
(node:9608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at drawChart (C:\Users\C2C04\Desktop\Charts\test.js:16:17)
```